# Event driven input vs turn based

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield

I am trying to recreate console game with JTextArea as console/output and JTextField as user input. Since the GUI is event driven I do not understand how could I stop the code from executing, to wait for user input before proceeding with opponents turn. The only solution I can think of is While(userTurn) and userTurn would be changed to false upon actionlistener is there a better way?

My console solution

```
 String getInput(String prompt){
        String inputLine = null;
      console.setTextConsole(prompt + " ");
        try{
            BufferedReader is = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            inputLine = is.readLine();
            if(inputLine.length() == 0) return null;

        }catch(IOException e){
            console.setTextConsole("IOException "+e);
        }
        return inputLine;
    }
```

I just called this getInput method and I proceeded with opponents turn.

What I want to accomplish is:

1. Opponents turn
2. Game waits for user
3. User types text into JtextField and presses enter
4. Game executes players command
5. Opponents turn again ..

Comment: Why is it that you've asked 10 question, yet only accepted one answer?

Comment: Is it a two opponents game or a one opponent vs. computer?

Comment: Event driven code means just that, code executed as a result of an event.  When the user presses the Enter key, you execute **just** the code that executes the player's command.  You could have another button for opponent's turn, which would execute the opponent's turn code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've written an example game so you can observe the difference. The computer and the user try to guess a random number between 0-2 inclusive. Who ever gets it right wins. If both get it right or both get it wrong its a draw.

**EDIT:** Updated GUI version

Here's the console program:

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ConsoleGame {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
        Random rand = new Random();
        boolean playAgain = false;
        int wins = 0, losses = 0, draw = 0;
        do {
            int num = rand.nextInt(3); // 0-2 inclusive
            System.out.println("Guess the number [0-2]: ");
            int guess = Integer.parseInt(console.nextLine());
            int computerGuess = rand.nextInt(3);
            System.out.println("You: " + guess + "\tComputer: " + computerGuess + "\tNumber: " + num);
            if (guess == num && computerGuess == num || guess != num && computerGuess != num) {
                draw++;
                System.out.println("Draw!");
            } else if (guess == num) {
                wins++;
                System.out.println("You win!");
            } else if (computerGuess == num) {
                losses++;
                System.out.println("Computer wins :(");
            }
            System.out.println("Play again [y/n]? ");
            playAgain = console.nextLine().startsWith("y");
        } while (playAgain);
        System.out.println("Wins: " + wins + "\nLosses: " + losses + "\nDraw: " + draw);
        console.close();
    }
}
```

Here's the GUI program:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class GUIGame extends JFrame {
    private JPanel contentPane;
    private JTextField textField;
    private JTextArea textArea;
    private boolean textReceived;

     /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    GUIGame frame = new GUIGame();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public GUIGame() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        setContentPane(contentPane);

        textField = new JTextField();
        textField.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            // user pressed 'enter' key,
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                textReceived = true;
                synchronized (textField) {
                    // notify game loop thread which is waiting on this event
                    textField.notifyAll();
                }
            }
        });
        contentPane.add(textField, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
        contentPane.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        textArea = new JTextArea();
        textArea.setFont(new Font("Consolas", Font.PLAIN, 12));
        textArea.setLineWrap(true);
        textArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        textArea.setForeground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        textArea.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        textArea.setEditable(false);
        scrollPane.setViewportView(textArea);

        // Start game loop in new thread since we block the thread when
        // waiting for input and we don't want to block the UI thread
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                playGame();
            }
        }).start();
    }

    private void playGame() {
        Random rand = new Random();
        boolean playAgain = false;
        int wins = 0, losses = 0, draw = 0;
        do {
            int num = rand.nextInt(3); // 0-2 inclusive
            textArea.append("Guess the number [0-2]: \n");
            int guess = Integer.parseInt(requestInput());
            int computerGuess = rand.nextInt(3);
            textArea.append("You: " + guess + "\tComputer: " + computerGuess + "\tNumber: " + num + "\n");
            if (guess == num && computerGuess == num || guess != num && computerGuess != num) {
                draw++;
                textArea.append("Draw!\n");
            } else if (guess == num) {
                wins++;
                textArea.append("You win!\n");
            } else if (computerGuess == num) {
                losses++;
                textArea.append("Computer wins :(\n");
            }
            textArea.append("Play again [y/n]? \n");
            playAgain = requestInput().startsWith("y");
        } while (playAgain);
        textArea.append("Wins: " + wins + "\nLosses: " + losses + "\nDraw: " + draw + "\n");
    }

    private String requestInput() {
        textField.setEnabled(true);
        textField.requestFocus();
        // wait on text field till UI thread signals a user input event
        synchronized (textField) {
            while (!textReceived) {
                try {
                    textField.wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        String input = textField.getText();
        textField.setText("");
        textField.setEnabled(false);
        textReceived = false;
        return input;
    }
}
```

Comment: Cheers I think I am starting to get it. One more thing if you could explain to me is what if I would expect different input e.g. at the beggining of game I want user to input his name and then expect him to press F and after that A / G etc.

Comment: You do that by passing prompt but that doesn't seem like the most universal way is there a different way? than reading back textarea?

Comment: @Higeath Yes, in fact there is a better, more intuitive way. Although it is similar to the proposed solution you mentioned in the question, that technique known as busy-waiting, eats up CPU resources. Blocking via [Object.wait()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait--) is a better alternative, see the updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I think this:

The ruler of the game is that who owns the turn. As long as the ruler make its move, the other must wait. How to implement this?

1. If the user owns the turn, he/she may enter text in the JTextField.
2. When he/she presses ENTER, the command must be validated. If it is OK, the turn must be transferred to the program, and meanwhile, the user shall not even be able to enter text in the JTextField. For example, disabling it:

```
    private void switchTurnToTheProgram()
    {
        jTextField.setEnabled(false);
    }
```

3. When the program finalizes its move, the turn must be transferred to the user again, and so, the jTextField must be enabled:

```
    private void switchTurnToTheUser()
    {
        jTextField.setEnabled(true);
    }
```

4. Last, you must determine in each case whose's first turn (to make the jTextField appear enabled or disabled).

The complete algorithm:

```
public void startGame(boolean userOwnsTheFirstTurn)
{
    if (userOwnsTheFirstTurn)
    {
        switchTurnToTheUser();
    }
    else
    {
         switchTurnToTheProgram();
         calculateNextMove();
         switchTurnToTheUser();
    }
}

public void userHasEnteredSomeCommand(String command)
{
    // This must be called from the correspondant actionListener.
    if (validateCommand())
    {
         switchTurnToTheProgram();
         calculateNextMove();
         switchTurnToTheUser();
    }
    else
    {
       ... log an error to the user ...
    }
}
```

To enhance the user's experience, maybe it will be useful to enable/disable the button along with the textField. In that case, you'll have to modify just the two methods `switchTurnToTheProgram` and `switchTurnToTheUser`.

Comment: The part that I am looking for is waiting for user to press enter without progressing further with the code

Comment: That's immediate in Java swing: You just have to open and paint the JPanel, add the listeners, and end. The panel will keep open, and there is a background thread listening for user events which will be the one calling the actionListener attached to the button.